# Possible to clone a SF page in Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

The actual problem: I need to make a callout to our property management system when a record is edited within Salesforce, make the change in our management system, and then (if successful) the change finishes in Salesforce (otherwise, display an error and don't make the change in Salesforce).

I cannot use a trigger for this, since the callout would have to be asynchronous in a trigger. From my research, creating a Visualforce page would be the way to go about it.

I would like this Visualforce page to be a copy of whatever the edit page for the applicable object is. I've been able to find generators online, but I would like to create something that pulls from the source. That way, if anything changes on the main layout, the new edit page changes as well. Is there a way to do this with Visualforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to retrieve a layout into a visualforce controller and then use that layout to construct your edit page.

in controller:

```
public class sotestcontroller {

public Metadata.Layout oppLayout {get; private set;} //layout
public opportunity myOpp {get;set;}

public sotestcontroller(){
myOpp = new opportunity();
List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(
                Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, 
                new String[]{'Opportunity-My Opportunity Layout'}
            );
        OppLayout = (Metadata.Layout) layouts.get(0);
}
```

The key thing here is that this line:

```
new String[]{'Opportunity-My Opportunity Layout'}
```

Should be of format:

```
new String[]{'OBJECT NAME-LAYOUT NAME'}
```

Then in visualforce page something like:

```
<apex:page controller="sotestcontroller">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opps" tabStyle="Opportunity" >
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!aControllerAction}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!aControllerAction}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!oppLayout!=null}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!oppLayout.layoutSections}" var="section">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!section.label}" collapsible="false">
            <apex:repeat value="{!section.layoutColumns}" var="col">
              <apex:repeat value="{!col.layoutItems}" var="item">
                  {! item.field }
                  <apex:inputField rendered="{! item.field == 'Name'}"
                   value="{! myOpp[item.field] }" 
                />
              </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Note on the input section I'm currently outputting the field names and just the opportunity name field ( inputField rendered where field name = 'Name') this is because not all of the fields can be created in this way, so you'll have to check through for the object in question, see which fields can't be created then create a rule to prevent them from rendering if they can't.

Also, I've just created a new opportunity to show the basic layout, but if you want edit you'll have to retrieve the id from somewhere, or use standard controller or something like that.

Any new fields would have to be added to the layout you've specified to appear on the page, but they should do so automatically if they are placed on that layout.

More details here:

https://medium.com/@charlie_77818/using-to-apex-metadata-api-to-recreate-standard-layouts-9ab1de200640